# Property not showing in report designer from partial entity class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework, reporting-services

Im making a report in the VS 2010 report designer, the main source of the data is the `Lines` entity. But I need an extra field from another entity `Parts`. So I added a partial class of Line with the extra property like so :

```
public partial class Line
{
    public string ShelfLocation
    {
        get
        {
            using (RSContext rs = new RSContext())
            {
                return rs.Parts.First(x => x.Code == this.Part).ShelfLocation;
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is I still cant see this extra field from the report designer :

[image]

How can I acheive this without creating another view?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 (both in same namespace) :

[image]

Comment: are you sure the partial class is in the same namespace of the original one ?

Comment: @FelicePollano yes both in same namespace.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Linq2Sql. Have you been able to solve it? I mean I have quite a few additional properties in a partial class which I don't really want to add manually to the report definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if there is a better solution but for the time being I added this manually to the report and it worked :

```
<Fields>    
...
    <Field Name="ShelfLocation">
          <DataField>ShelfLocation</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
   </Field>
</Fields>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to make sure both classes are in the same namespace.

You may consider create an object of type Line and verifying that you can see the new property you added:

```
var testLine = new Line();
testLine.ShelfLocation  // <-- Does ShelfLocation show up as a valid property? Do your other properties like Debit, Id, etc. also show up?
```

Comment: Yes it passes the above test. Both the context and the partial class are in RS namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Linq2Sql. All properties from a custom partial class were not visible in the report designer.

**To solve the problem**

1. Open the Properties dialog of the *.dbml and clear the 'Custom Tool' property. The *.designer.cs file disappears then.
2. Use the sqlmetal.exe in the 'Pre-build events' to generate the *.designer.cs manually

   > sqlmetal /namespace:"$(ProjectName)"
   >   /code:"$(ProjectDir)DataModel.designer.cs"
   >   "$(ProjectDir)DataClasses1.dbml"

After these manipulations the additional properties were recognized successfully.